# How php connect to sql server via using active directory

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, codeigniter-3, sqlsrv, php-7.2

I trying to connect a linux server to ms sql on the database server via using AD. But When I tried it is not allows to connect.

```php
$serverName = "xxxxxxx";
$uid = "xxxxxx";
$pwd = "xxxxxxx";  
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $uid, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database"=>"xxxxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);  

if( $conn )  
{  
     echo "Connection established";  
}  
else  
{    
     echo '<pre>' ;
     die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors() , true)); 
     echo '</pre>' ;
}

sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

> Login failed for user 'xxxxxx'

Comment: You say you're trying to use AD, but then pass a username and password. If you're using AD, you don't pass a username and password as the user's credentials that is running the application is used. You'll also need Kerboros set up on the Linux server, which is not a simple task. Is it set up?

Comment: Try with `$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"xxxxxx");`

Comment: I got this message.

SSPI Provider: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:48)

Comment: You need to configure kerberos or use sql server authentication instead of windows authentication